# Httpclient error while using ngx-datatable in angular

Tags: angular, httpclient, ngx-datatable

I am trying to use ngx-datable on my angular project but I am seeing the following error on my angular project. I am not sure what the exactly error means . However, I am not sure how to resolve it. I have attached all the files that I have changed below. You can replicate the error by creating a new angular project using `ng new randomName` and running `npm install @swimlane/ngx-datatable --save` then changing/ adding the files below. Please help, what is wrong? Thanks

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/common/http/http.d.ts:81:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/common/http) which declares HttpClient has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version 
of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

81 export declare class HttpClient {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpClient,HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
    HttpClient,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpClientModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component:html:

```
<ngx-datatable 
      class="material"
      [limit]="8" 
      [rows]="rows" 
      [rowHeight]="50" 
      [columns]="columns"
      [columnMode]="'force'" 
      [sortType]="'multi'" 
      [headerHeight]="50" 
      [footerHeight]="50">
</ngx-datatable>
```

App.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
// import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

export interface Data {
  dummyData: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
  // ,encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public data: Data;
  public columns: any;
  public rows: any;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.columns = [
      { name: 'Name' },
      { name: 'Company' },
      { name: 'Genre' }
    ];

    this.http.get<Data>('../../assets/dummyData.json')
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        this.rows = res.dummyData;
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

dummyData.json:

```
{
    "dummyData": [
        {
            "name": "Escape Room",
            "company": "Columbia Pictures",
            "genre": "Horror"
        },
        {
            "name": "Rust Creek",
            "company": "IFC Films",
            "genre": "Drama"
        },
        {
            "name": "American Hangman",
            "company": "Hangman Productions",
            "genre": "Thriller"
        },
        {
            "name": "The Upside",
            "company": "STX Entertainment",
            "genre": "Comedy"
        },
        {
            "name": "Replicas",
            "company": "Entertainment Studios",
            "genre": "Sci-Fi"
        },
        {
            "name": "After Darkness",
            "company": "Grindstone Group",
            "genre": "Drama"
        },
        {
            "name": "Glass",
            "company": "Universal Pictures",
            "genre": "Superhero"
        },
        {
            "name": "Close",
            "company": "Netflix",
            "genre": "Action"
        },
        {
            "name": "The Final Wish",
            "company": "BondIt Capital",
            "genre": "Horror"
        },
        {
            "name": "Serenity",
        "company": "Aviron Pictures",
        "genre": "Drama"
    },
    {
        "name": "Miss Bala",
        "company": "Columbia Pictures",
        "genre": "Thriller"
    },
    {
        "name": "Velvet Buzzsaw",
        "company": "Netflix",
        "genre": "Comedy"
    }
]
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **HttpClientModule** from providers in **app.module.ts**.

Here you can see how to configure http in angular

[Angular Link](https://angular.io/guide/http)

I think this will help for you

Comment: Thank you, the link was informative, but I removed it and still face the same problem

Comment: Can you delete the node_modules and try installing again with the npm install comment on your project folder and then try